# server closed the connection unexpectedly python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, ubuntu, docker-compose

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

and  when I run with docker exec ...

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not translate
 host name "potgres" to address: No address associated with hostname
```

my port seems like that :

```
0.0.0.0:5431->5431/tcp, 5432/tcp
```

even when I change port number in file.yml , there is nothing happen!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you spelled your hostname correctly?

psql: error: could not connect to server: could not translate
 host name "potgres" to address: No address associated with hostname

It looks like you misspelled postgres as potgres.